# wrap child div text onto next line when browser resized

Tags: html, css

How do I get a child's  full text content to move to the next line when the browser is resized and it no longer fits?

so it ends up like this

This text is in - first child
This text is in second child

```css
.child1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.child2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child1">
    This text is in - first child
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    This text is in second child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did attempt it, thats why im here.... im struggling to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` or `float:left` instead `display:inline` for next line

```css
.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child1">
    This text is in - first child
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    This text is in second child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add media query

```
.child1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.child2 {
  display: inline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 100px) {
  .child2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```